# How can I see the file or directory named passed to Vim from the command line?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'd like to set up my .vimrc so that NERDTree is open whenever vim (or MacVim) is called from the command line with a directory argument, but closed when vim is called with a file argument. I looked through the list of vim's built-in variables but couldn't find anything that looked promising.

Comment: I'm not sure how to actually do this, but you'll probably need to use the arglist. Take a look at `:h arglist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked up `arglist` per Alligator's advice. Ended up with the following:

```
if argc() > 0 && isdirectory(argv(0))
    autocmd VimEnter * silent NERDTree
endif
```